# Getting error with istream operator overloading

Tags: c++

```cpp
point2D &operator>>(istream &in, point2D &p)
{
    char c = ' ';
    cout << "please input x and y coordinate : ";
    in >> p.x >> c >> p.y;
    return p;
}
```

> Define an overloaded input operator >> for such a structure variable of the type circle. In the body, after a prompt, read in the circle center via the input operator defined above for a point of type point2d and a floating point number for the radius from the character input stream reference passed as a parameter.
>
> Check that the radius read in is not negative, otherwise write a message onto the standard character error output stream and reverse the sign.

Here is my try:

```cpp
circle &operator>>(istream &input, circle &cir)
{
    //cout << "input center:" << endl;
    point2D p;
    istream(input, p);
    //input >> cir.center.y;
    //cout << "please input radius : ";
    input >> cir.radius;
    if (cir.radius < 0)
    {
        cout << "in operator>> : negative radius, sign changed";
        cir.radius = cir.radius * -1;
    }
    return cir;
}
```

I am getiing an error:

> no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::istream' (aka 'basic_istream<char>')

Comment: the stream operator should return the stream so that it can be chained your function signature looks wrong to me. also not sure what youre trying to do here: `istream(input, p);` that should probably be `input >> p;`

Answer (score 0):

**First** overloaded `operator>>` should return `istream&` as shown below.

**Second** since we pass the second argument(which is `cir&` in this case) as reference there is no need to return it because any changes you make on `cir` will already be reflected on it.

**Third** validate if the input was successful. If the input was not successful then leave the passed argument in **default state**.

```
/* no need to return cir because it is already passed by reference as argument,
so any changes you make on cir it will be reflected on it*/

std::istream &operator>>(istream &input, circle &cir)
{
    //cout << "input center:" << endl;
    point2D p;
    input >> p ; //this assumes you've overloaded `operator>>` for point2D class
    //input >> cir.center.y;
    //cout << "please input radius : ";
    input >> cir.radius;
    //always validate if input was successful
    if(input)
    {
        if (cir.radius < 0)
        {
            cout << "in operator>> : negative radius, sign changed";
            cir.radius = cir.radius * -1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cir = circle();//leave the cir in default state
    }
    
    return input;//return the istream object that was passed as argument
}
```

Comment: You should also validate that `operator>>` is successful before processing its output. IOW, make sure that `input >> cir.radius` actually reads a value before doing anything with `cir.radius`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes i have added it in my answer. I was just adding(editing) that(validating) part in my answer . Now i have added it.